# create password and access with password only

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Trying to make an admin panel where the admin user can create passwords for the access page. You'll need the password to access the login/register page. I've been trying to make this with json web tokens. I've used the MEAN-stack for this:

access Schema

```
var accessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: String
});
```

create jwt

```
function createAccessToken(password) {
    var payload = {
        sub: password._id,
        iat: moment().unix(),
        exp: moment().add(7, 'days').unix()
    };
    return jwt.encode(payload, config.ACCESSCODE_TOKEN_SECRET);
}
```

Login and signup

```
app.post('/auth/loginaccess', function (req, res) {
    Access.findOne({ password: req.body.password }, function (err, access) {
    if (!access) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid password' });
    }
    access.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid password' });
        }
        res.send({ tokenauth: createAccessToken(access) });
    });
  });
  getPasswords();
});

app.post('/auth/signupaccess', function (req, res) {
    Access.findOne({ password: req.body.password }, function (err, existingPw) {
    if (existingPw) {
        return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Password is already taken' });
    }
    var access = new Access({
        password: req.body.password
    });
    access.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        }
        res.send({ tokenauth: createAccessToken(result) });
    });
  });
});
```

ComparePassword and save schema

```
accessSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var access = this;
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(access.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            access.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

accessSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password, done) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        done(err, isMatch);
    });
};
```

the creation of the password works and is correctly encrypted and inserted into the database. But when I try to login it throws the 401 error inside app.post('/auth/loginaccess').

Why is this happening?
And any tips to improve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: you send res.status(401) to client. can you check value received from client and retrieved password , are they same?

Comment: the payload on both signup and login are the same, which I tested with admin.  Example, I type in 'admin' as the password, which created this bcrypt hash: '$2a$10$XHtPJ8G3hiNzZFM1gSTVS.T5ZWBKKSfayICuoe0.vMpE37GXZDAS.'   When I decrypt it online, it says it matches, but I still get 401 thrown

Comment: Value of isMatch should return 1 or true. if bcrypt.compare return false you code return 401. value of err should not set when compare is success. so when success value of err should be true

Comment: It doesn't get so far though. It throws the 401 at the first if-statement if(!access)

Comment: Can it be that it compares the encrypted entry in the database, encrypts it again to then check against the database entry? If that is the case, how would I go about solving it?